# Dell XPS 15 - applications don't scale in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm currently stuck with the scaling of my external monitor.

This is my setup:

- Dell XPS 15 9570, 4k display, nVidia Geforce 1050Ti, running ubuntu 18.04.
- nouveau disabled
- 1x external monitor connected via HDMI (I tried one monitor with 1920x1080 and one with 3440x1440 resolution)

My problem is that a change of the scaling has only an influence on the side panel. Not a single desktop icon, application, application title bar scales at all when I change it.

This are the things I tried while running both monitors (internal and external) or only the external one (`xrandr --output $INTERNAL_DISPLAY --off`):

1. Change resolution in Setting -> Devices -> Screen Display:
   This changes the scale of the side bar and the side bar icons exactly like I want them but nothing else changes.
2. Change the scale via `xrandr`

   ```
   xrandr --output DP-1-3 --auto --scale 2x2
   ```

   Now my external monitor visualizes only a quater of the content. The scaling of the sidebar, icons, applications and application title bars stays consistent.
3. Change the dpi value via `xrandr`

   ```
   xrandr --dpi 220
   ```

   This doesn't do anything in my case.
4. Change the font size via `gsettings`

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
   ```

   or the `unity-tweak-tool` (I guess they do both the same thing).
   This helps me to adjust the font size to my desires but obviously has no influence on applications, application title bars etc.
5. Tried some approaches with the `xorg.conf` file but once I create and reboot it, I don't even get past the log in anymore.

Does anyone have an idea what else I could try to scale the applications/application title bars? I manage to scale Firefox via the `about:config` but this has no influence on the application title bar.